# Discord bot does not run on Heroku using Python

Tags: python, heroku, bots, discord

I made a Discord bot and it's working on usual interpreter, but when I try to run it on Heroku, it does not make any error, but also the bot is still offline, which means it has not been executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to create a file named `Procfile` (no extension) and put `worker: Botolski.py` inside it.

[More info on procfiles](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile)

Hope this helps! If there's anything else I can do, let me know.

Comment: Thank you! I also forgot about requirements.txt and runtime.txt
But it's working now.